# Accessing values in a hash in an array in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, hash

I'm new to rails (but work with php on a daily basis as my job). I'm having trouble getting the value of a hash.
 
In my controller I have the following:

```
@artists = RSpotify::Artist.search(params[:q])
```

This runs a search for artists containing whatever query is passed to it. So searching for 'Ozzy' would return results for Ozzy.
 
In my view I'm running the following code which loops through and outputs the name and the first value of the image.

```
<%= @artists.each do |artist| %>
    <%= artist.name %><br />
    <%= a = artist.images.first %><br />
<% end %>
```

the output of artist.images.first is:

```
{"height"=>640, "url"=>"https://i.scdn.co/image/0f9515867c122afc298e626c10afbb189165e4f5", 
"width"=>640}
```

What I want to do is access the url part so I can add it to an image tag as the source but I'm struggling to do it.
 
It is definitely a Hash - running the following proves this.
 
    artist.images.first.class
 
Running this results in an error (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass) and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.
 
    artist.images.first[:url]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call:

```
artist.images.first.try(:fetch, "url")
```

it will return the url or nil if images.first is nil. Mind that it will raise

```
KeyError: key not found: "url"
```

if images.first is a hash but doesn't have the url key.
In that case you could also provide a default url:

```
artist.images.first.try(:fetch, "url", "/default_image.jpg")
```

Comment: Note that this appears to be a Rails thing. It's not part of Ruby. (Unfortunately.)